# getting an error while using mpl_toolkits.basemap

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap  - is not working in ipython

Getting error as - No module named basemap

I'm using jupyter

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have basemap installed. It is a separate package. If you are using conda, you can install it with:

```
conda install basemap
```

If not, you can install with:

```
pip3 install --allow-external basemap --allow-unverified basemap basemap
```

(the `--allow-stuff` is because basemap is not on PyPI because its [installers are too big](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/198).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```